# Code for a dedicated "rotation" button

Tags: objective-c, ipad, xcode4.2

I am building a venue layout app for the ipad that will use different classes of objects (tables /chairs/ stage segments etc) for the user to add to the floor plan and adjust.

In other apps I have used UIgestures for the panning and rotation of objects:

```
- (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view]; 
recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x, recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y); 
[recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];
}

- (IBAction)rotateMe:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{

recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.rotation);
recognizer.rotation = 0;
}
```

However the objects for this app will be smaller than normal fingers will allow for multiple touch gestures.

I would like to opt for a "Rotate" button within the view that when pressed and held will allow a single touch on anyobject to custom rotate  it.

Or if anyone can guide me to a better option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a project on GitHub called KTOneFingerRotationGestureRecognizer that is a custom rotation gesture recognizer that uses a single finger to do rotations. You touch down on an object and spin it as if it had an axle in it's center. It might work for you, depending on how small your shapes are. You might need to make your views a little larger the the images they contain (add some padding, in other words.)

Comment: Thanks for this @Duncan it is certainly the format i'm looking for. However, I'm having problems switching it OFF in a toggle Button implementation. I assume that is because the coding adds the rotation method to the UIView and then releases? I'm not advanced enough to know how to combat that - ?

Answer (score 0):

Should be fairly simple to do. A touch of the rotate button will toggle rotation on and pressing another object will perform the rotation. Use `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation` to rotate.

```
yourObject.view.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(yourVariable*M_PI/180.0);
```

Increment yourVariable by whatever angle you choose and it should rotate a bit each time, i.e incrementing by 90 would rotate the object 90 degrees each time you touch the object.

Comment: I have used this for the more standard 90 deg rotation. What I'm needing is a smaller incremental style.